# Getting invalid data output with multi dimensional arrays in alpaca js library

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

I am using the latest build of alpaca 1.5.15 and, when i try to load the schema which have multi dimensional arrays and data it is not rendering correctly. I think it is considering the first value and displaying. I guess this is bug in the library. Below is the code sample and the screen shot. Please help me.

```css
$('#div').alpaca({
    "schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": false,
        "properties": {
            "email": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "properties": {}
            },
            "file1": {
                "type": "array",
                "required": false,
                "items": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "required": false,
                    "items": {}
                },
                "properties": {}
            },
            "file": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "properties": {}
            },
            "password": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "pattern": {},
                "properties": {}
            },
            "check": {
                "type": "boolean",
                "required": false,
                "default": true,
                "properties": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "options": {
        "focus": false,
        "type": "object",
        "helpers": [],
        "validate": true,
        "disabled": false,
        "showMessages": true,
        "collapsible": true,
        "legendStyle": "button",
        "fields": {
            "email": {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Email Address",
                "helpers": [],
                "validate": true,
                "disabled": false,
                "showMessages": true,
                "renderButtons": true,
                "data": {},
                "attributes": {},
                "allowOptionalEmpty": true,
                "autocomplete": false,
                "disallowEmptySpaces": false,
                "disallowOnlyEmptySpaces": false,
                "fields": {}
            },
            "file1": {
                "type": "array",
                "label": "File Upload1",
                "helpers": [],
                "validate": true,
                "disabled": false,
                "showMessages": true,
                "collapsible": true,
                "legendStyle": "button",
                "toolbarStyle": "button",
                "actionbarStyle": "top",
                "items": {},
                "rubyrails": false,
                "hideToolbarWithChildren": true,
                "fields": {}
            },
            "file": {
                "type": "file",
                "label": "File Upload",
                "helpers": [],
                "validate": true,
                "disabled": false,
                "showMessages": true,
                "renderButtons": true,
                "data": {},
                "attributes": {},
                "allowOptionalEmpty": true,
                "autocomplete": false,
                "disallowEmptySpaces": false,
                "disallowOnlyEmptySpaces": false,
                "fields": {}
            },
            "password": {
                "type": "password",
                "label": "Password",
                "helpers": [],
                "validate": true,
                "disabled": false,
                "showMessages": true,
                "renderButtons": true,
                "data": {},
                "attributes": {},
                "allowOptionalEmpty": true,
                "autocomplete": false,
                "disallowEmptySpaces": false,
                "disallowOnlyEmptySpaces": false,
                "fields": {}
            },
            "check": {
                "type": "checkbox",
                "rightLabel": "Sign me up for the News Letter!",
                "label": "Newsletter",
                "helpers": [],
                "validate": true,
                "disabled": false,
                "showMessages": true,
                "renderButtons": true,
                "fields": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "email": "Joe Smith",
        "file1": [
            [
                "d1",
                "d2"
            ],
            [
                "d1",
                "d2",
                "d3"
            ]
        ],
        "password": "MyPassword",
        "check": true
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I think you're using it wrong, can you tell me more about what you want to do? Can you please upload a simple image illustrating what you want to do, can you do that? Thanks.